# Why to use Reverse Shell?

Tags: port-forwarding, reverse-shell

I know that reverse shells get the victim to connect to us, but I heard that people mostly use reverse shells Why use reverse shells when hacking a network outside our local network as we have to do port forwarding? It only brings some extra work.

Comment: It seems to me it takes less work to set up port forwarding (or simply open a port) on your gateway then it is to do on the gateway for the machine you're deploying the backdoor on.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your other question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232781/when-to-use-reverse-and-bind-shells  please edit that question if you can refine it rather than posting a new question. Also pay attention to the tag edits on your other question. And this looks more like a networking question than a security question.